# jquery: Appending url extension to existing iFrame url

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to change my iframe on button click by appending `nfl/` to `http://espn.go.com/`. Unfortunately, nothing happens when the button is clicked. I would make a jsfiddle but everytime I save the fiddle, it just goes to espn.com on pageload

```
<iframe src="http://espn.go.com/" id="GMapsframe" height="300px" width="600px"></iframe>

<button id="button1" onclick="GMapTest(nfl/);">TEST</button>
```

jquery:

```
function GMapTest(facilityID) {
         var url = 'http://espn.go.com/';
         $('#GMapsframe').attr('src', url + facilityID);
         return false;
                    }
```

EDIT:
Added `return` to `onclick="return GMapTest('nfl/');"` however now is just goes to the new website instead of inserting it into the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `name='GMapTest'` to html, added `return` and passed the name in the parameters within the onclick.

```
<button id="button1" onclick="return GMapTest('GMapsframe','nfl/');">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it like this:

```
GMapTest('nfl/');
```

The `facilityID` is a string.

```
<button id="button1" onclick="GMapTest('nfl/');">TEST</button>
```

Comment: Answer makes sense, but still not getting a change.